# when i approve review,show error ,i delete the reviews,product page and home page is ok,catalog page error:

Tags: magento, review, magento-1.9.1

SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`color`, `e`.`color_value`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`open_amount_min`, `e`.`open_amount_max`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`open_amount_max`, `e`.`open_amount_min`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`necklace_length`, `e`.`necklace_length_value`, `e`.`occasion`, `e`.`occasion_value`, `e`.`shoe_type`, `e`.`shoe_type_value`, `e`.`color`, `e`.`color_value`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_category_id`.`category_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `at_inventory_in_stock`.`is_in_stock` AS `inventory_in_stock`, `mv`.*, `bs`.*, `ra`.`reviews_count` AS `num_reviews_count`, `ra`.`rating_summary` AS `num_rating_summary` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_inventory_in_stock` ON (at_inventory_in_stock.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND ((at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=0) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1))
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT `report_event`.*, COUNT(`event_id`) AS `num_view_counts` FROM `report_event` WHERE (event_type_id = 1) GROUP BY `object_id`) AS `mv` ON mv.object_id = e.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT `sales_flat_order_item`.`product_id`, SUM(`qty_ordered`) AS `ordered_qty` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` GROUP BY `product_id`) AS `bs` ON bs.product_id = e.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `ra` ON e.entity_id = ra.entity_pk_value AND ra.store_id=1 WHERE ((at_category_id.category_id IN('147', '201', '148', '149', '150', '155', '151', '156', '218', '204', '205', '206', '207'))) GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `num_view_counts` DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: where did you get this error in frontend or backend?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed any extension related to product review than please disable it and than try.Please flush cache and re-login in admin.

Comment: thanks for your reply,i have disable the review,and try again,but the error still

Comment: catalog page : also show Trace:
#0 /home/../public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/../public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/../public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)